# Firebird Data Access Designer (DDEX) installation

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, firebird

hi i want to use firebird library , and i followed its instruction as below , but i get "The referenced component 'FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird' could not be found." error.

instruction :

Prerequisites

1. Make sure that you have Visual Studio .NET 2005 Standard or higher edition.
2. Express editions are not supported.

Registry update

1. Remember to update the path in FirebirdDDEXProviderPackageLess32.reg or FirebirdDDEXProviderPackageLess64.reg, places where to update it are marked %Path%.
2. Install the .reg file into the registry.

Machine.config update

Add the following two sections to machine.config (located usually at C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config and C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config on 64-bit system).

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <configSections>
    ...
    <section name="firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    ...
  </configSections>
  ...
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      ...
      <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=%Version%, Culture=%Culture%, PublicKeyToken=%PublicKeyToken%" />
      ...
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  ...
</configuration>
```

And subst:

```
%Version% With the version of the provider assembly that you have in the GAC.
%Culture% With the culture of the provider assembly that you have in the GAC.
%PublicKeyToken% With the PublicKeyToken of the provider assembly that you have in the GAC.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a reference to the assembly in your project?  If not, right click in the solution explorer on references and choose `add reference`.  Find the Firebird client assembly and add it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... it is not available in the list of .NET components... although I have added it to the GAC with gacutil !

Comment: @Sam: My understanding of when things show up in the list of available components and when they don't.  I have had the same experience where I add one with gacutil and still don't see it.  Nonetheless, you should be able to add it by clicking on the `Browse` tab of that Add Reference dialog.  Then browse directly to the file.

Comment: thank you, in my case it was a wrong Version in machine.config file

Comment: @Sam: I'm glad you figured it out. Those types of problems can be frstrating sometimes, and there are few hints as to what the real issue happens to be.